# What is a Perfect Word™?

Tags: pattern, word-property

<sub>This is in the spirit of the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22What+is+%22+%22Word%22+-missing+user%3A463+is%3Aquestion) puzzles.</sub>

---

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a Perfect Word™.

Use the following examples below to find the rule.

| PERFECT WORD™ | NOT PERFECT WORD™ |
| --- | --- |
| UNDERGROUND | SUBWAY |
| AFTERSHAFT | FEATHER |
| ENTERTAINMENT | AMUSEMENT |
| IONIZATION | NEUTRALIZATION |
| PHYTOGRAPHY | BOTANY |
| CALENDRICAL | PERIODICAL |
| REDECLARED | REASSIGNED |
| TORMENTOR | TORTURER |
| INGESTING | CONSUMING |
| RESTORES | REJUVENATES |

Here is a CSV version:

```
PERFECT WORD™, NOT PERFECT WORD™
UNDERGROUND, SUBWAY
AFTERSHAFT, FEATHER
ENTERTAINMENT, AMUSEMENT
IONIZATION, NEUTRALIZATION
PHYTOGRAPHY, BOTANY
CALENDRICAL, PERIODICAL
REDECLARED, REASSIGNED
TORMENTOR, TORTURER
INGESTING, CONSUMING
RESTORES, REJUVENATES
```

Comment: Aah interesting ^_^

Comment: I guess all the ™s are necessary?

Comment: @MarkRogers, it is a series of such puzzles. You can see the other of the same type by clicking on the tag [word-property]

Comment: Its seems a little strange that the TM is after just the word Phrase or Word, can you even trademark a single common word?  I guess so.

Comment: @MarkRogers JLee started this type of puzzle - I have no idea why. Perhaps there is an explanation in his earlier puzzles?

Comment: @MarkRogers The TM symbol primarily just artistic flair, with a meaning similar to double quotes (e.g. "Perfect Word"). The use of the symbol also hints that there is some property or method, defined by OP, that distinguishes the trademarked words from other words. The specific trade-name often provides a hint as to what this property or method is. (Note this all is my own speculation/observation, and should not be taken as hard facts.)

Comment: May I suggest renaming this as "Hotshot Words™"

Comment: @JoeFrambach Hotshot makes it too obvious for me. Besides, there aren't many words in English that follow that rule (even less so if we add 1 more letter to the rule). And what makes something Perfect could be speculative, but for me such words are Perfect.

Comment: "Abracadabra" is too long and "Beriberi" is too obvious, I agree

Comment: @JoeFrambach I could call them Magical?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

A perfect word is

> a word where the first three and the last three letters of the word are the same.

Example

> und-ergro-und and aft-ersh-aft

How I found my answer

> I first saw that every perfect word had at least twice the same two letter combination. After that I found out that it was a three letter combination at the start and end of the word.

Comment: I'm curious as to why the term `Perfect` is used for these words.